# How does Drew Dreschel fly so far on American Ninja Warrior?

Tags: kinematics

Drew Dreschel is in a league of his own on the shelf grab and wing nut obstacles (wait, is this a physics question?  Please trust me, it is--see the section below).

SPOILER (competition results below):

> He seemed to easily win both skill competitions.

What is his secret to flying so far (here's video showing him and his competitors on the shelf grab: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h15Qa5ErX7s; here they are doing the wing nuts obstacle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1E-6WYBKmQ)?  It seems like his competitors fly in a high parabola while his flight seems might more flat and fast.  Is this correct?  If so how does he do it?  Basically what is he doing different that's giving him such an edge?

## How this is a physics question

I'm looking for an "explanation of observed physical phenomena" (allowed Help Center topic #1: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) related to flight of humans in a gymnastics situation.  Specifically: What is he doing with his body to fly farther?  What effect does this have from a physics perspective?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about physical exercise rather than physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind If you watch the show it actually involves a good amount of physics. An answer to this question can be physics in nature if it focuses on how the contestants become projectiles on the obstacles mentioned in the question. I don't think this should be closed. If this can be reopened, I can provide an answer that is based in physics.

Comment: Explanations of observed physical (#1 from the Help Center) totally applies here; it's exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: Thank you @AaronStevens--I hope that you're allowed to, this is a very interesting question that I was just asking my wife after watching the show, and I'd love to see what the physics behind it could be.  Some equations would be awesome.  :)

Comment: Simply asking "What is the physics if X?" Are generally bad questions because they are usually too broad to be usefully answered in this Q&A format.

Comment: @KyleKanos I know it is poorly asked, but the wing nut obstacle is essentially a projectile motion problem. The physics of this obstacle can therefore easily be explained.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Who is Drew Dreschel? What exactly is he doing? You need to describe what he is doing (also provide a diagram or image, or a video link) and explain what you think is remarkable about it. All relevant information should be contained in your question. It should not be necessary for other users to do research to understand what you are asking.

Comment: The trick is I'd need to provide links to video of the whole competition.  I'll see if I can find that.  I was hoping someone here might be a fan and have seen it.  But I'll look.

Comment: @bob Just supply a video link of the wing nut challenge special that aired recently

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czj81b6EsW4

Comment: @AaronStevens video not available.

Comment: The problems I have with this question in its current form (v3) are: 1. It is not clear what you are asking to anyone who hasn't watched this Drew Dreschel in action. 2. It is not clear what sort of "physics" explanation you are looking for. "What is he doing with his body?" is asking about the technique he uses. It would be useful if you explained a specific thing he does, and then asked why *that thing* makes him fly farther than others.

Comment: @sammygerbil The link works fine for me

Comment: Okay I added links to videos.  Also see that @AaronStevens did, thanks!

Comment: @bob The same link was copied onto your answer twice

Comment: @ACuriousMind I could see that being easier to answer, but my question *is* what is he doing.  How could someone swinging the same as the others generate a faster flatter parabolic flight?  He's not swinging higher.  But he's got so much more speed.  How could that be possible?  I'm looking for suggestions, for ideas.  And for physics to back it up.

Comment: I'm wondering if the other competitors are treating their bodies as simple pendulums but he's treating his as a double-pendulum, swinging his hips as he releases to generate extra speed, but I have no idea if this is feasible--if this would help physics-wise.  I'm thinking someone with physics know-how has to have a good hunch here.

Comment: @bob Both your video links are identical. DD does not appear to have any significant advantage in the shelf grab, another contestant matches his performance. What is there to explain? What are you asking is *feasible*? If DD does it, it must be feasible.

Comment: If you're asking for *what* he's doing, then you probably want to look at [sports.se] to get that answer.

Comment: @AaronStevens Are you a subscriber?

Comment: @sammygerbil A subscriber to what? If you are referring to the youtube video I put a link to, no, I am not a subscriber to the channel that posted the video.

Comment: @sammygerbil That's odd, I fixed that problem (just double-checked it).  Not sure why you're seeing the same thing at both links.

Comment: @bob I've seen both videos now. I don't see what there is to explain. DD is not "in a league of his own" as far as I can see. His performance is equalled in the 1st video, and his opponent gets close in the 2nd (he might have made it with another attempt). He has a better technique (one commentator says "Look at that huge backswing!") but I don't see anything special that requires an explanation using physics.

Comment: I'd like to see this question salvaged, but I think that would require moving a lot of material from the linked videos so that the question stands on its own --- most users here won't watch nine minutes of video just to figure out what a "wing nut obstacle" is. You might like to read about how a pole vaulter's body can clear an obstacle while their center of mass is always below the obstacle; [see e.g.](https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/physics-of-pole-vaulting.html).

Comment: Sports physics is an interesting topic, but it is usually a *complicated* topic done in any detail and unhelpfully inexact if the details are elided.  Those papers that I have seen usually look at established sporting events (running, swimming, diving, elements from tennis and baseball, and so on...).